# Getting flow control warning for a Lisp interpreter I wrote in C

Tags: c, lisp

I've been working through SICP and tried my hand at creating a LISP interprater. I keep getting the following warnings:

```
$ make littleLisp
cc     littleLisp.c   -o littleLisp
littleLisp.c:309:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
$ make littleLisp
make: `littleLisp' is up to date.
$ ./littleLisp 
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
5.000000
```

I'm not quite sure what this is referring to as my main method is returning 0. Is my "in.lisp" file not being called properly?

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/rahul1346/8596118b834ecf41b1d9

Any ideas?

Also, what are your thoughts on the interperater itself?

Here is the fxn ending on 309:

```
long interpret_list(long scope, long first, long last) {
    parent[first] = scope;
//  printf("interpret_list %d %d %d\n", scope, first, last);
    long i, j, brace;
    if (last>=first && in_special(first)) {
//      puts("OK");
        special(scope, first, last);
    } else {
        child_count[scope] = 0;
        i = j = first; brace = 0;
        while ( i <= last) {
            if (!strcmp(seg[i], "(")) brace++;
            if (!strcmp(seg[i], ")")) brace--;
            if (brace == 0) {
                interpret(scope, j, i);
                child[scope][child_count[scope]++] = j;
                j = i + 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (brace) {
//          puts("Format error!!");
            exit(2);
        }
        if (is_function(seg[first])) {
            apply_function(seg[first], scope);
        } else {
            return scope;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the function that ends on line 309 of "LittleLisp.c". Oh, and find where you used `gets` and replace it with some alternative (e.g., `fgets`).

Comment: it is returning scope?

Comment: Path exists that does not return a value

Comment: Any idea why im gettng the gets error? I use fgets but it still errors... any thoughts.?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways your function can fall off the end without returning:

1. When `last>=first && in_special(first)` is true.
2. When `is_function(seg[first])` is true.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not following?

Comment: There are two places in your function that have `if` in them, as I've identified in my answer. Only if both of those conditions are false, does the `return scope` line get reached.